# argv[argc] ==?

Tags: c, argv

My professor and a couple of students are arguing about whether `argv` is null terminated or not. My friend wrote a small program and it printed out `null` but another kid said that he is probably simply reading into blank memory. Can someone solve this discussion?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

From the Standard:

> 5.1.2.2.1  Program startup
>   ...
>     -- argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

So, yes; argv is null terminated

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Why then the argc anyway?

Comment: I don't know **why**. But it makes writing some programs a little easier by avoiding having to walk the `argv` array just to count the arguments.

Comment: Umm.. why: argc: `if(argc <= 3) /* not enough arguments */` I think better than `if(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]) <= 3)`

Comment: @Jack: `argv` is a pointer; `argv[0]` is also a pointer. In all likelihood `sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])` evaluates to `1` ... anyway, your idea is similar to what I said (not having to walk to `argv` array).

Comment: Still, the Operating System (in case of Linux, the ELF loader) has to walk argv, since it's only passed argv in execve().

Comment: I have noticed that getopt() can crash if argv[argc] is not a NULL pointer (when using it in the Clide library, https://github.com/gbmhunter/clide-cpp).

Comment: @pmg But why is `char* argv[argc]` a pointer to `NULL` in general? Isn´t it actually an array of pointers to char? Like `char* a[i]` is also a pointer to char, not to `NULL` or `void`.

Comment: @RobertS: independent of the names used, by the c specification `char *argv[argc]` declares an array named `argv` capable of holding `argc` pointers to `char`. When passed to a function, the array gets converted to a pointer to its 1st element (so a pointer to pointer to `char` [this is why it is usual to see `main(int argc, char **argv)`]) losing information about size (`char *a[10]` has 10 elements; `char **a` is a pointer --- if the pointer points to an array, there is no way of knowing how many elements the underlying array has).

Answer (score 44):

According to the standard, "argv[argc] shall be a null pointer" (5.1.2.2.1).

Comment: Why and how did it become standard? Any idea?

Comment: @Reigel: The man page for `exec` from 1979 (http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/v7vol1.pdf) shows that this predates the standard by quite a bit, and contains a possible hint as to why it's this way: "Argv is directly usable in another execv because argv[argc] is 0."