# C and execve(3) arguments

Tags: c, exec, constants, ptrace, execve

I'm working on a project that basically does the same thing as `strace(1)` using `ptrace()`. Basically we have a controller.c program that takes an executable as an argument and it outputs any system calls made by the executable (for example `% controller ls -l`)
We are using the `execve()` to run the executable file, but we are having a little bit of trouble. execve takes the following arguments

```
 execve( const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[] )
```

where filename in this instance would be `"ls"`, and `argv[]` is a list of the arguments for the given file name. So we have something that looks like this (in the C file)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[],char *envp[]){
  pid_t child;
  child = fork;

  if(/* CHILD */){
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0, NULL, NULL);

    if(argc == 2) {
      execve(argv[1],NULL,envp);
    }
    else {
      execve( argv[1], /* ARGUMENT LIST */, envp);
    }

  } else /* PARENT */ {
    //PARENT CODE 
  }
}
```

So if we get an executable, for example `controller ls -l`, `where argv[0] = "controller"`, `argv[1] = "ls"`, and `argv[2] = "-l"`, how can we pass the correct parameter at "ARGUMENT LIST" (where the arguments in this case is just `"-l"` but it could be more)?

Basically, how do we initialize an array of type `const char *` such that the array has the argument values for the executable? Do we even need to worry about having extra values in the array and just past `argv` for ARGUMENT LIST?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't work with C much. Does this syntax work for taking a sub-array of some array? (I'm going to give it a try)

Comment: First, you don't need that inner `if/else` at all, and seond, why not just `&argv[1]` for the middle argument to `execve`?

Comment: `argv + n` simply is an array/pointer that points to the `n`th element of argv. It's equivalent to `&argv[n]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass `argv + 1` (to skip your program's name). `argv + 1` is a pointer to an array starting from the second element of `argv`, which is the executed program's name. `argv + 1` is equivalent to `&argv[1]`, and you can use whatever style you prefer.

As mentioned in the comments, section 5.1.2.2.1 of the standard specified that `argv` is indeed null-terminated. The section below is retained for completeness.

In case C doesn't guarantee `argv` is null-terminated (and it's not clear to me whether it does or not), you can do:

```
char **new_argv = malloc((argc-1) * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1) new_argv[i] = argv[i+1];
```

and use `new_argv` for the argument list.

Comment: I think you'll find that C does in fact guarantee that the argv and envp arrays are null-terminated.

Comment: @Neil - did you find proof of that somewhere?  I just took a quick look in the spec, but I didn't anything that jumped out at me.

Comment: @CarlNorum: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc) mentions that 5.1.2.2.1 of the standard specifies that `argv` is null terminated, which is what I've always believed to be true. `envp` has to be terminated by a NULL in order to be able to tell the end of it.

Comment: @AusCBloke, I'm looking at that right now and I see the line.  I don't know how I missed it earlier - it's staring me right in the face: "`argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.".  `envp` doesn't really enter into it, since it's not standard C anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
execve(argv[1], argv+1, envp);
```