# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when not using arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I could be doing this completely the wrong way, but considering this will be for personal use, having it not be that efficient is okay.

When ran as `./todo -r`, it works.

When ran as `./todo -a`, it works.

When ran as `./todo`, it gives me `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argc < 1) {
    printf("Not enough variables.");
    }

    if(strcmp("-r",argv[1])==0) {
        printf("\n");

        system("cat .todo");
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(strcmp("-a",argv[1])==0)   {
    char str[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(".todo","a");
    printf("\n\nTODO list\n\n");
    for(;;) {

        printf("~ ");
        fgets(str,256,stdin);
        if(strcmp(str,"\n")==0) {
            fclose(f);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

        fprintf(f,str);
        }
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(argc < 1)` -- should be `if(argc < 2)`.

Comment: Also need to check the return value of fopen for 0.

Comment: Hint: when pasting code to SO, please remove tabs first. As you can see, indentation in the question code is not quite right...

Answer (score 2):

`argv[0]` is the program executable name, and it's counted towards `argc`.

So `./todo` has `argc=1`, but `argv[1]` is NULL, which will cause a problem for `strcmp()`.

See [argv[argc] ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc)

Change your test:-

```
if (argc < 2) 
{
  printf("Not enough variables.");
  return 0; // do this, otherwise we'll plough straight on..
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm 99% sure, that `argv[argc]` is required to be `NULL`, so it *is* defined... :)

Comment: @hyde is correct, but changing the check to `argc < 2` still isn't enough.  See @KenWayneVanderLinde's answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need `argc < 2` rather than `argc < 1`.

Additionally, you probably want to return from the `if`, to stop the rest from executing:

```
if(argc < 2) {
  printf("Not enough variables.");
  return /* some appropriate value here */;
}
```

Comment: +1 - but 'probably'?  I think 'definitely', since the code right after that `if` starts accessing the `argv` array.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: You're right that I could (fairly) confidently remove the "probably". Then again, other courses of action are possible (e.g. some default action). As it stands, his code doesn't account for this, but it's his choice what he ends up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your file handle and then still trying to write to it:

```
if (...) {
   fclose(...); <--potentially closing it, depending on the if() results
}
fprintf(...); <--potentially writing to a closed handle.
```

This is a BAD idea.

Comment: fprint, sorry. either way... writing to a closed handle.

Comment: Shouldn't writing to a closed `FILE*` just fail cleanly with error? So not a BAD idea (such as UB), just kinda pointless/stupid (especially without checking for write errors). But I did not check docs, so I guess it could be UB or something, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: The `break` prevents writing to the closed handle, but there can still be a crash if the file open fails in the first place (resulting in `f == NULL`).