# string throwing segmentation error in c++

Tags: c++, string

I am getting segfault error when I tried the following. I am getting some arguments dynamically to the program. I have to concatenate all of them into a single string and operate on it. I have written the following code for concatenating all the arguments into one string.

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv){
   string input;
   for(int i=1;i<=argc;i++)
       {

            input+= argv[i]+string(" ");

       }
       //code for operating on the string. code not yet written
   return 0;
   }
```

I am getting segfault when the arguments are more. If the arguments are 10-20, then there is not segfault. But when the arguments are 100, I am getting segfault. I tried using char[] in c++. but that also giving the same error. How to handle this?

Comment: Your `<=` should be `<`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison in your `for` loop is wrong. You are checking for less-than or equal to instead of just less than.

The following line

```
for(int i=1;i <= argc;i++)
//            ^^
```

should be

```
for(int i=1;i < argc;i++)
//            ^
```

Comment: Note that argv[argc] is not out of bounds memory and is defined to be a NULL pointer. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc)

Comment: Quite correct. Thanks, updated.

Comment: Thanks @CaptainObvlious. I have put it because in my unix sys, argv[0] was giving the program name. SO, I thought I should loop from 1 to argc instead of 0 to argc-1. Thank you very much!!